# Transform an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [condition] => AND
    [rules] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => query-builder-rule
                    [query] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => transactionDate
                            [field] => transactionDate
                            [type] => date
                            [input] => datepicker
                            [operator] => equal
                            [value] => 2017-05-02 00:00 - 2017-05-03 00:00
                            [rule] => transactionDate
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => query-builder-group
                    [query] => Array
                        (
                            [condition] => OR
                            [rules] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => query-builder-rule
                                            [query] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => firstname
                                                    [field] => firstname
                                                    [type] => string
                                                    [input] => text
                                                    [operator] => equal
                                                    [value] => Doe
                                                    [rule] => firstname
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => query-builder-rule
                                            [query] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => lastname
                                                    [field] => lastname
                                                    [type] => string
                                                    [input] => text
                                                    [operator] => equal
                                                    [value] => Doe
                                                    [rule] => lastname
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => query-builder-rule
                                            [query] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => email
                                                    [field] => email
                                                    [type] => string
                                                    [input] => text
                                                    [operator] => equal
                                                    [value] => Doe
                                                    [rule] => email
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need this transformed into this array

```
Array
(
    [condition] => AND
    [rules] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => transactionDate
                    [field] => transactionDate
                    [type] => date
                    [input] => datepicker
                    [operator] => equal
                    [value] => 2017-05-02 00:00 - 2017-05-03 00:00
                    [rule] => transactionDate
            )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [condition] => OR
                    [rules] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => firstname
                                    [field] => firstname
                                    [type] => string
                                    [input] => text
                                    [operator] => equal
                                    [value] => Doe
                                    [rule] => firstname
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => lastname
                                    [field] => lastname
                                    [type] => string
                                    [input] => text
                                    [operator] => equal
                                    [value] => Doe
                                    [rule] => lastname
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => email
                                    [field] => email
                                    [type] => string
                                    [input] => text
                                    [operator] => equal
                                    [value] => Doe
                                    [rule] => email
                                )

                        )

                )



        )

)
```

I am trying to do this recursively but i hit the wall.

My current code is this but it's not really correct.

```
public function transform($request)
{
    $request = json_decode($request, true);

    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'rules') {
            foreach ($value as $rKey => $rValue) {
                if (!is_array($rValue['query']['rules'])) {
                    $this->parsedRequest[$key] = $rValue['query'];
                } else {
                    $this->transform(json_encode($rValue['query']));
                }
            }
        }

        $this->parsedRequest[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

This just overwrites existing values. I can't get my head around it. I tried using `array_walk_recursive` but i couldn't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I need this recursively because i don't know how much layers will there be. These arrays are only examples.

EDIT:
`var_export`

first array:

```
array ( 'condition' => 'AND', 'rules' => array ( 0 => array ( 'type' => 'query-builder-rule', 'query' => array ( 'id' => 'transactionDate', 'field' => 'transactionDate', 'type' => 'date', 'input' => 'datepicker', 'operator' => 'equal', 'value' => '2017-05-02 00:00 - 2017-05-03 00:00', 'rule' => 'transactionDate', ), ), 1 => array ( 'type' => 'query-builder-group', 'query' => array ( 'condition' => 'OR', 'rules' => array ( 0 => array ( 'type' => 'query-builder-rule', 'query' => array ( 'id' => 'firstname', 'field' => 'firstname', 'type' => 'string', 'input' => 'text', 'operator' => 'equal', 'value' => 'Doe', 'rule' => 'firstname', ), ), 1 => array ( 'type' => 'query-builder-rule', 'query' => array ( 'id' => 'lastname', 'field' => 'lastname', 'type' => 'string', 'input' => 'text', 'operator' => 'equal', 'value' => 'Doe', 'rule' => 'lastname', ), ), 2 => array ( 'type' => 'query-builder-rule', 'query' => array ( 'id' => 'email', 'field' => 'email', 'type' => 'string', 'input' => 'text', 'operator' => 'equal', 'value' => 'Doe', 'rule' => 'email', ), ), ), ), ), ), )
```

second array:

```
array ( 'condition' => 'OR', 'rules' => array ( 0 => array ( 'type' => 'query-builder-rule', 'query' => array ( 'id' => 'firstname', 'field' => 'firstname', 'type' => 'string', 'input' => 'text', 'operator' => 'equal', 'value' => 'Doe', 'rule' => 'firstname', ), ), 1 => array ( 'type' => 'query-builder-rule', 'query' => array ( 'id' => 'lastname', 'field' => 'lastname', 'type' => 'string', 'input' => 'text', 'operator' => 'equal', 'value' => 'Doe', 'rule' => 'lastname', ), ), 2 => array ( 'type' => 'query-builder-rule', 'query' => array ( 'id' => 'email', 'field' => 'email', 'type' => 'string', 'input' => 'text', 'operator' => 'equal', 'value' => 'Doe', 'rule' => 'email', ), ), ), )
```

Comment: Could you use `var_export()` so we can have the array(s)?

Comment: I think array is still not correct.

Comment: @AgamBanga explain please

Comment: @housefrommars In last its showing as ` 'rule' => 'email', ), ), ), )`

Comment: @housefrommars check this https://repl.it/Hdtl

Comment: @AgamBanga it was something wrong with arrays but it was not that, i accidentally concatenated two arrays into the second one. having commas after is not a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I wrote the code for you. Function name is `simplify`, your array is in `$arr`.

```
<?php
function simplify($arr) {
    if(is_array($arr))
        foreach($arr as $key => &$a) {
            if($key == 'rules') {
                if(is_array($a))
                    foreach($a as $key2 => &$a2) {
                        if(isset($a2['query'])) {
                            if(isset($a2['query']['rules'])) {
                                $a2['query'] = simplify($a2['query']);
                            }
                            $a2 = $a2['query'];
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

    return $arr;
}

$arr = array(
    'condition' => 'AND',
    'rules' => array(
        0 => array(
            'type' => 'query-builder-rule',
            'query' => array(
                'id' => 'transactionDate',
                'field' => 'transactionDate',
                'type' => 'date',
                'input' => 'datepicker',
                'operator' => 'equal',
                'value' => '2017-05-02 00:00 - 2017-05-03 00:00',
                'rule' => 'transactionDate',
            ) ,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            'type' => 'query-builder-group',
            'query' => array(
                'condition' => 'OR',
                'rules' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'type' => 'query-builder-rule',
                        'query' => array(
                            'id' => 'firstname',
                            'field' => 'firstname',
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'input' => 'text',
                            'operator' => 'equal',
                            'value' => 'Doe',
                            'rule' => 'firstname',
                        ) ,
                    ) ,
                    1 => array(
                        'type' => 'query-builder-rule',
                        'query' => array(
                            'id' => 'lastname',
                            'field' => 'lastname',
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'input' => 'text',
                            'operator' => 'equal',
                            'value' => 'Doe',
                            'rule' => 'lastname',
                        ) ,
                    ) ,
                    2 => array(
                        'type' => 'query-builder-rule',
                        'query' => array(
                            'id' => 'email',
                            'field' => 'email',
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'input' => 'text',
                            'operator' => 'equal',
                            'value' => 'Doe',
                            'rule' => 'email',
                        ) ,
                    ) ,
                ) ,
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
);
$arr = simplify($arr);
```